# SignalR 2.2.0 Hub function OnDisconnected

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

Following are the 2 issues I faced while developing a simple Chat app using signalR and angularJS for front end:

1. On disconnection of a particular client, the call to Ondisconnected hub function reaches the server after about 10-15 minutes on average.
2. When the call finally reaches the server function OnDisconnected (which is defined to make only that client offline) subsequently multiple calls are received from all the other connected clients, and hence all the clients go offline, even when there's no problem with their connections.

Here are the chatHub functions:

```
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
      public void UserOffline(string EMail)//makes user offline by the mailId
      {
        IEnumerable<ConnectionId> _connectionIds = database.GetConIds(EMail);
        bool successFlag = database.LogOff(EMail);
        if (successFlag == true)
        {
            foreach (ConnectionId item in _connectionIds)
            {
                Clients.Client(item.connectionId).broadcastOffline();
            }
            IEnumerable<Client> _clients = database.GetAllClients();
            Clients.All.broadcastUsers(_clients,null);
        }
      }

      public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
       {
         if (stopCalled == false)
         {
             string mailid = database.GetMailOfConId(Context.ConnectionId);
             UserOffline(mailid);
         }
         return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
       }
    }
```

Comment: I'm stuck on these issues for the past few days... please help

Answer (score 0):

We can set the Disconnection TimeOut in Global.aspx Page like this

```
  protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   // Make long polling connections wait a maximum of 110 seconds for a
   // response. When that time expires, trigger a timeout command and
   // make the client reconnect.
   GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(110);

  // Wait a maximum of 30 seconds after a transport connection is lost
 // before raising the Disconnected event to terminate the SignalR        connection.
  GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

  // For transports other than long polling, send a keepalive packet every
  // 10 seconds. 
  // This value must be no more than 1/3 of the DisconnectTimeout value.
  GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

  RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
  }
```

For more information You Just refer to this [http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#disconnecttimeout]